# How can I get Vim to not break DocBlock comments?

Tags: vim, comments, autoformatting

```
/**
 * Example Comment
 */
```

When I press enter after `Comment` Vim autoindents but leaves the cursor lined up with the `*` characters. How can I get Vim to add the `*` and a space so that my comment lines up with the `E`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to modify the value of the `formatoptions` (short name `fo`) Vim option, like this:

```
:set fo+=or
```

The `r` option enables the behavior in insert mode; `o` enables it when using <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd> in normal to switch into insert. Try Vim's builtin help for details:

```
:help formatoptions
```